# Converting nested for loops to flattened list comprehension when outer variable is used in inner scope

Tags: python

I have a pair of nested loops where the operation inside the inner loop depend on both the loop elements.

```
def ngram(inp='', mn=2, mx=60):
    """
    EG inp='the' => ['th', 'the', 'he']
    """
    out = []
    for i in range(0, len(inp) + 1 - mn):
        for j in range(i + mn, min(i + mx + 1, len(inp) + 1)):
            out.append(inp[i:j])
    return out
```

I thought I'd make it into a list comprehension instead of a repeated `append`, but I can't seem to figure out how I'm going to refer to the outer `i` when expanding the inner `j`.

What I got to was from this:

```
[[i, [j for j in range(i + mn, min(i + mx + 1, len(inp) + 1))]]
    for i in range(0, len(inp) + 1 - mn)]
```

Which when `inp='the'` `mn=2` and `mx=60` yields: `[[0, [2, 3]], [1, [3]]]`

Which has the right information for producing `[inp[0:2], inp[0:3], inp[1:3]]`

Leading me to:

```
[[inp[i:j] for j in range(i + mn, min(i + mx + 1, len(inp) + 1))]
    for i in range(0, len(inp) + 1 - mn)]
```

Which is: `[['th', 'the'], ['he']]`

But it should be possible to flatten this in the above statement without needing to surround it with:

```
[g for lst in […above…] for g in lst]
```

Can it be flattened in the prior step somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def ngram(inp='', mn=2, mx=60):
    return [inp[i:j] 
            for i in range(0, len(inp) + 1 - mn)
            for j in range(i + mn, min(i + mx + 1, len(inp) + 1))]
```

In general, whenever you have a for loop of this form:

```
result = []
for sub_1 in collection:
    for sub_2 in sub_1:
        …
            for sub_n in sub_(n - 1):
                result.append(element)
```

You can construct an equivalent `list` comprehension of the following form:

```
[element for sub_1 in collection for sub_2 in sub_1 … for sub_n in sub_(n - 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```py
def ngram(inp='', mn=2, mx=60): 
    return [
        inp[i:j]
        for i in range(0, len(inp) + 1 - mn)
        for j in range(i+mn, min(i + mx + 1, len(inp) + 1))
    ]
```

Comment: Nothing, that's what I meant to do and couldn't seem to get right.

Comment: Ah, I see. Nested loops very naturally translate to list comprehensions in some cases, quite straightforward here.

Comment: I almost had it, just reversed: `[inp[i:j] for j in range(i+mn, min(i+mx+1, len(inp)+1)) for i in range(0,len(inp)+1-mn)]`
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined```

Comment: to be fair, my natural instinct would be to reverse it too