# Is there a way to populate a large list with elements from a smaller list whose length may not be an integer multiple of the length of the large list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which I know will be large, but could vary in length, say `length = 52`.
 I have a smaller list of odd integers which could also vary in length but will never be a similar size to the large_list,
 e.g.

```
small_ints=[31,33,35,37,39,41]
```

I would like to get the small list copied into my large list to give

```
large_list = [31,31,31,31,31,33,33,33,33,33,35,35,...41]
len(large_list) = 52
```

It isn't important for each number to be repeated the exact same number of times, approximately may be enough.

I almost got somewhere with a preallocated list something like `large_list=[None]*53` but then got errors, now I can't even find the Stack Overflow page that gave me a useful hint on that.

Comment: Are you trying to randomly fill the large list using values from the smaller list?

Comment: I don't think you've explained the logic of how the small list is copied. Why not just append the values in the small list to the large list? You say you `have a list` but in the code you tried, it looks like you are trying to *make* this list.

Comment: As @MarkMeyer said, why not just append? Since it seems like you're just trying to create a list for weighted chance.

Comment: This is apparently some sort of home work.  There is no reason to "pre-allocate" a python list unless told.

Comment: I am trying to make a ramp (large_list) but the size of the ramp will vary, I may need 3 or 4 across the data. The values for the ramp have to be within a certain range (small_list). Its not homework, I'm 48!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
numbers = [31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]
size = 11

n_copies = size // len(numbers)
excess = size % len(numbers)

result = sorted([element 
                 for i in range(n_copies) 
                 for element in numbers] + numbers[:excess]) 

print(result)
print(len(result))
```

Output:

```
[31, 31, 33, 33, 35, 35, 37, 37, 39, 39, 41]
11
```

This makes the largest possible number of copies of `numbers` that, when combined, will have no more elements than `size`. If there is a difference, it is filled with elements from `numbers`. The whole thing is then sorted to group identical values together.

You can change `size` to 52 (I used 11 so the output would be shorter).

Comment: Thank you gmds that is perfect. Can I ask about the 2 for loops? I see there is no colon or indentation for the second for loop - I am guessing this is a form of programming I have not come across yet. Works perfectly, much appreciated.

Comment: @Windy71 I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045255/converting-nested-for-loops-to-flattened-list-comprehension-when-outer-variable/55045363#55045363) answer of mine will help you.